# Django url path render issue,

Tags: python, django

### I got a failure on url path issue when try to do an exercise with Django
"
raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: URL route 'post/Title:Title/' uses invalid converter 'Title'.
"
1.I've tried change the variable Title to other path name but still no working.
2.I check the setting.py with eplease help me.

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from mblog.views import homepage, showpost

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', homepage),
    path('post/<Title:Title>/', showpost),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Post
from datetime import datetime


# Create your views here.
def homepage(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()  # SQL SELECT * FROM mblog_post(creat from models)
    now = datetime.now()
    return render(request, 'index.html', locals()) 


def showpost(request, Title):
    try:
        post = Post.objects.get(Title = Title)
        if post != None:
            return render(request, 'post.html', locals())
    except:
        return redirect('/')
```

setting.py

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'key is erase!!'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mblog.apps.MblogConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'jerryblog.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'jerryblog.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'zh-hant'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Taipei'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Answer (score 0):

in your urls.py do this:

```
path('post/<str:Title>/', showpost)
```

Comment: What amazing!! it works!! but why? because the web address is string?

Comment: @CodingNC "str" is the type of the parameter, here in your case Title is an string, so it's "str"

Comment: Ok, so it would not a dict container? I mean  it's not a key:value pair?

Comment: @CodingNC [here is the official django doc about urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/), this will help you understand better

Answer (score 0):

You have to try this it will help you to solve your error.You cant pass same name of value in primary key you should put "slug" either "int"

```
path('post/<slug:Title>/', showpost),
```

And in view change the argument of post variable as slug=title.

```
def showpost(request, Title):
    try:
        post = Post.objects.get(slug= Title)
        if post != None:
            return render(request, 'post.html', locals())
    except:
        return redirect('/')
```

Comment: Sorry ,I've try your solution for debug but it doesn't work , 
I don't have any define with slug any object name or method or database field and still hunger for understand for why need change to slug:Title

Comment: For this u have to first add SlugField in models.py of your project mblog.And share your models.py too